# How to replace a particular line in a file using ansible?

Tags: text, replace, ansible

I want to use ansible to go to the nignx configuration file and and replace the `ssl_certificate` line with my own.
This is the line in `nginx.conf`

```
ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
```

All I want to know is what module and how do I use it to replace the path of the certificate to what I want.

Comment: It is a bit more complicated then that. since servers might have different path I want ansible to only recognize the line by "ssl_certificate" parameter and then delete the whole line. It would also be good if it doesn't delete the commeted "#ssl_certificate" line.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
- name: modify
  replace:
    path=/path/to/nginx.conf
    regexp="^(ssl_certificate\s+)[^\n]+$"
    replace="ssl_certificate \"/required/file/path/here\";"
```

Comment: This works but the problem is that it also replaces a line called "ssl_certificateKey".

Comment: Modified answer to include space \s in regex

Answer (score 0):

*To replace a particular line in a file using ansible* you can use the [lineinfile_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html)

```
- name: Replace a localhost entry with our own
  lineinfile:
    path: nginx.conf
    regexp: '^    ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";'
    line: '    ssl_certificate "/your/path/server.crt";'
```

In my example I get this diff

```
<     ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
---
>     ssl_certificate "/your/path/server.crt";
```

But consider using the [ansible role for NGINX](https://github.com/nginxinc/ansible-role-nginx) .